# Polymer "dom-if" using toggle and item property

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

**Goal**

I'm wanting to use a toggle to filter (or hide via dom-if) elements based on the toggle itself and a boolean property of the element.

So with an array of objects:

```
[{..., active: true}, {..., active: false}]
```

I want to hide the "active:false" objects with the toggle.

**Problem**

I can't figure out how to get the if function "_showAlert(item)" to fire on toggle switch or more importantly if this is even the way I should go about this using Polymer.  I'd appreciate guidance on either.

```
<paper-toggle-button checked="{{activeOnly}}">Active Only</paper-toggle-button>
<paper-listbox>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[alerts]]">
        <template is="dom-if" if="{{_showAlert(item)}}">
            <paper-item>...</paper-item>
        </template>
    </template>
</paper-listbox>

<script>
    (function() {
        'use strict';
        Polymer({
            is: 'alert-list',
            properties: {
                alerts: {
                    type: Array
                },
                activeOnly: {
                    type: Boolean,
                    notify: true
                }
            },
            ready: function(){
                this.alerts = [{..., active: true}, {..., active: false}];
            },
            _showAlert: function(item) {
                // The alert item will have a boolean property called "active"
                return (item.active || !this.activeOnly);
            }
        })
   })();
</script>
```

*I've just appended some data in the ready function for now for development purposes.  I can get the list to display just fine and I can verify the binding between the toggle and the "activeOnly" property is working.*

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you would want your `showAlert` function to re-evaluate every time either `item.active` or `activeOnly` change. To achieve that you have to pass them to the funciton as arguments (also see [docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#dependent-properties)).

```
   <template is="dom-if" if="{{_showAlert(item.active, activeOnly)}}">
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think about that because passing a property I already had access to seemed initially counter-intuitive.

Comment: Yes, I kind of agree. You don't even have to use the arguments necessarily in the function. It is just a way to let the framework know when the function should be triggered.

Comment: Side note: If an item was missing the "active" property it never calls _showAlert and never renders, even if the conditional in the function would have evaluated to true with the undefined value.  So I either needed to ensure all the data has the property or just send item.  Let me know if that doesn't sound right though.  Kind of confusing..

Comment: Yes, that is correct, I've added a link to the documentation. You could also use a wildcard like `item.*`. This will also trigger if any sub-property of item changes, however, depending on the complexity of your item that may trigger too often when it is not really necessary.